# Apex Retrieve Tasks Assigned to Current User For All Contact Roles on an Account

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have an Apex class whose purpose it is to retrieve and delete overdue tasks on the contact role (related to an account) that the user just called. I need to modify it so that it queries for all overdue tasks assigned to the user on ALL contact roles on the account but am struggling to get the right query.

Here is a portion of the code in question, the part I think is most relevant:

```js
/***************************************************
Brief Description: Deletes overdue Tasks or Events.
****************************************************/
public class DSDenali_DeleteOverDueActivities {

private static List<Task> followUpTasksToDelete = new List<Task>(); 
private static List<Event> followUpEventsToDelete = new List<Event>();
private static Map<Id, Set<String>> ownerOfActivities = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();

@InvocableMethod (label = 'DialSource Denali Delete Overdue Activities')
public static void gatherData(List<Data> requests)
{
    Map<Id, String> results = new Map<Id, String>();

    for (Data request : requests)
        results.put(request.contactRoleID, request.assignedTo);

    for (Id key : results.keySet())
    {
        Set<String> assignedToValues = parseAssignedTo(results.get(key));
        System.debug('assignedToValues: ' + assignedToValues);
        ownerOfActivities.put(key, assignedToValues);
        System.debug(ownerOfActivities);
    }

    queryAndFilterData();
    deleteOverdueActivities();
}

//Query for the Tasks and Events and filter the ones to delete
private static void queryAndFilterData()
{
    List<Contact_Role__c> contactRoles = [SELECT Id, 
                                                (SELECT Id, Owner.UserRole.Name, OwnerId FROM Tasks WHERE status != 'Completed' AND ActivityDate <= :system.TODAY() AND Type__c = 'Outbound Call'),
                                                (SELECT Id, Owner.UserRole.Name, OwnerId, Description FROM Events WHERE EndDateTime <= :system.NOW())
                                         FROM Contact_Role__c
                                         WHERE Id IN :ownerOfActivities.keySet()];

    for (Contact_Role__c contactRole : contactRoles)
    {
        for (Task currentTask : contactRole.Tasks)
        {
            if (ownerOfActivities.get(contactRole.Id).contains(currentTask.OwnerId))
            {
                if (currentTask.OwnerId != '0050B000006ET37' && currentTask.Owner.UserRole != NULL && Pattern.matches('.*Altair.*', currentTask.Owner.UserRole.Name))
                    followUpTasksToDelete.add(currentTask);

                else if (currentTask.OwnerId == '0050B000006ET37')
                    followUpTasksToDelete.add(currentTask);

                else 
                    continue; 
            }

            else if (ownerOfActivities.get(contactRole.Id).contains('ALL'))
            {
                if (currentTask.Owner.UserRole != NULL && Pattern.matches('.*Altair.*', currentTask.Owner.UserRole.Name))
                    followUpTasksToDelete.add(currentTask);

                else 
                    continue;
            }
        }

        for (Event currentEvent : contactRole.Events)
        {
            if (ownerOfActivities.get(contactRole.Id).contains(currentEvent.OwnerId) && currentEvent.Description == NULL)
            {
                if (currentEvent.OwnerId != '0050B000006ET37' && currentEvent.Owner.UserRole != NULL && Pattern.matches('.*Altair.*', currentEvent.Owner.UserRole.Name))
                    followUpEventsToDelete.add(currentEvent);

                else if (currentEvent.OwnerId == '0050B000006ET37')
                    followUpEventsToDelete.add(currentEvent);

                else 
                    continue; 
            }

            else if (ownerOfActivities.get(contactRole.Id).contains('ALL') && currentEvent.Description == NULL)
            {
                if (currentEvent.Owner.UserRole != NULL && Pattern.matches('.*Altair.*', currentEvent.Owner.UserRole.Name))
                    followUpEventsToDelete.add(currentEvent);

                else 
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }                                   
}

//Delete overdue Events/Tasks
private static void deleteOverdueActivities()
{
    try{
        delete followUpTasksToDelete;
    }

    catch (DmlException e){
        System.debug('The following error occured (DSDenali_DeleteOverDueActivities): ' + e);
    }

    try{
        delete followUpEventsToDelete;
    }

    catch (DmlException e){
        System.debug('The following error occured (DSDenali_DeleteOverDueActivities): ' + e);
    }
}

//Parse the CSVs of possible owners
private static Set<String> parseAssignedTo(String assignedTo)
{
    Set<String> assignedToValues = new Set<String>();
    assignedToValues.addAll(assignedTo.deleteWhitespace().split(','));
    return assignedToValues;
}

public class Data
{
    @InvocableVariable (required=true)
    public String assignedTo;

    @InvocableVariable (required=false)
    public Id contactRoleID; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(updated after OP posted more code and asked for code review)

It's not bad code, could use some comments. Consider posting it in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (although not many SF-related posts end up there) or on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com

**`gatherData()`**

Your input variable (after some parsing) is `Map<Id, Set<String>>` where key is contact role's id. That set of strings for users (owners) is bit misleading. At a glance you immediately ask yourself why it can't be `Set<Id>`. Only deep down in the code you see that apparently "All" is one of allowed values. This is... not great. I'd be tempted to make 2 methods here, one taking legit `Map<Id, Set<Id>>` and other taking simply `Set<Id>` if you know that you're effectively skipping the second parameter.

**`queryAndFilterData()`**

You have only one query and it's not in a loop, very good. **My trick (from before edit) won't work for you** (you don't really have the `Account__c` or however is the field called anywere in the input, you have only record ids. If you want to check / delete all tasks for roles under this account cleanest might be to use two queries

```sql
// 1st the helper to collect all accounts...
Set<Id> allAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Contact_Role__c WHERE Id IN :ownerOfActivities.keyset()]).keyset();

// then the outline of the main query would be bit like this
SELECT Id,
    (SELECT ... FROM Tasks WHERE ...),
    (SELECT ... FROM Events WHERE ...)
FROM Contact_Role__c
WHERE Account__c IN :allAccounts
    AND ...
```

I'd **check how much of this filtering logic could be pushed to the query itself** rather than manually inspecting each returned row. I mean look at that:

Imagine we're going the simple route (ignoring concept of "All" users) and let's say you have another `Set<Id> allUsers;` variable (composed out of all ids mentioned in all your data pieces)

The query for Tasks could become something as simple as

```sql
(SELECT Id
FROM Tasks
WHERE Status != 'Completed'
    AND ActivityDate <= TODAY 
    AND Type__c = 'Outbound Call'
    AND OwnerId IN :allUsers
    AND (OwnerId = '0050B000006ET37' OR Owner.UserRole.Name LIKE '%.Altair.%')
)
```

You still have to loop through them to verify whether each can really really be deleted (it's not enough to match out of all users, it has to check also if it's OK for user on this particular Contact_Role__c, right?) but something like that should return less rows and no more regular expression matching... should be bit faster.

**I wouldn't have a magic variable for that one special owner's id** like that. Ideally there would be something else that describes this special user (role? profile? custom field on User record? permission to "Author Apex" in profile?). At the very least move it to helper `Id` variable at top of the file so it's not copy-pasted all over the place. And ask your business user what should happen if that guy (default task owner? some integration account?) ever leaves the company because poo poo will hit the propeller hard.

If you'll get comfortable with this version of the query the "ALL" version would become even simpler? No "all users", no "magic id" & job done?

```sql
(SELECT Id
FROM Tasks
WHERE Status != 'Completed'
    AND ActivityDate <= TODAY 
    AND Type__c = 'Outbound Call'
    Owner.UserRole.Name LIKE '%.Altair.%'
)
```

Don't trust random guy on internet who doesn't know your business process but yeah, there's some room for improvement. Just test thoroughly :)

**`deleteOverdueActivities()`**

This is not great try-catch pattern. You just raise it in debug log but silently swallow the error. Make it fail hard (let the error bubble up to user) or do some proper error handling like inserting something to helper Log__c object maybe or sending an email / chatter post to admin...

**`parseAssignedTo()`**
Not bad. I expect it explodes horribly when you pass a null to it. You're kind of protected from it by marking the variable required in last lines but I think this annotation applies only to Flows. Calling it from other Apex code isn't protected enough.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input!! I will certainly take a look at your helper variable method suggestion. I have edited the post to include the code for the entire class; if you have a second to take a look at it and see if it changes which approach I should take. I seriously appreciate you - you're the man.

Comment: Thank you once again, so much. Sorry for the slow reply, it has been extremely hectic this week, as I'm sure it has been for you. I like your much cleaner query All...I think I should be able to extrapolate what I need form this to complete the project. At the very least you've given me a fantastic starting point.

Comment: Good luck! Thanks for coming back & closing the loop :) If you get anywhere exciting consider posting it as answer for benefit of next generations ;)